# Monitoring Solutions for IBM iSeries & AIX

Tags: aix, iseries-navigator

I'm curious to know if anyone out in StackOverflow works with monitoring solutions for the IBM iSeries & AIX? We're looking into solutions that provide a single-pane of glass into both systems, rather than two separate solutions.

Any thoughts or input is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. ....

Comment: There are very few AIX readers here on StackOverflow. https://ittoolbox.com has a forum for AIX that is active and helpful, but the best place to ask AIX questions (IMHO) is on the IBM community/support website. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter!